# Game Theory Moving Around Coins

Tags: group-theory, puzzle

To start off, we have coins arranged in the following order:

..C.. A

F.. D.. B

..E.. G

The goal of this game is to return these letters into alphabetical order: A, B then C, D, E then F, G in the rows from top to bottom. On each move you may rotate any triangular block of letters, such as the blocks ADB or DEG, by one or two rotations clockwise.
For example, if we rotate the block ADB by one rotation clockwise, our coins would look like:

..C.. D

F.. B.. A

..E.. G

What is the least number of moves required, with justification?

Comment: Game theory? Looks more like group theory to me. You've got the group generated by the 3-cycles ACD, ABD, BDE, CDF, DFG, and DEG, and you're trying to find the shortest expression for ABEFC as a product of those elements and their inverses.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to do it in three moves:
CAFDBEG    ADFCBEG   ADCEBFG   ABCDEFG

It cannot be done in 2 moves since only D and G are in their aphabetic positions, and any two triangles will leave at least one of the 5 others outside it unmoved.

Comment: But remember, we can only rotate clockwise. Wont this change the answer? I believe in all your moves, you rotated counterclockwise. Thus it would actually take 6 moves?

Comment: @Andy One rotation counterclockwise=two rotations clockwise. The question specified one or two rotations on each move.